# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() does not work

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I have a strange behaviour when trying to start a video file with Java.

Here's the code:

```
File f = new File("Y:\AAA\DVD2013_GDL_(SEP)\Videos\0005000po8jy.mpg");
String[] cmd = new String[3];
cmd[0] = "cmd.exe";
cmd[1] = "/C";
cmd[2] = "\""+f.getAbsolutePath()+"\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

For some reason, the video is not starting. When pasting the path to cmd, the file starts without problems.

Now, when I change the path to:

```
Y:\AAA\DVD2013_GDL_(SEP)\Video Dateien\0005000po8jy.mpg
```

the above code works. Note, that I have simply changed the folder Name from 'Videos' to 'Video Dateien'.

Does someone have an idea, why my code does not work under the described circumstances? Btw, I am using Java 1.7.

Edit: I do not an Exception and there is no freeze or other strange behaviour.

Thanks for your help, 
klib

Comment: Have you tried [`Desktop.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))?

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop.open() works! But does this have any drawback? Is there another case, where the code fails to start the file? And I still can't understand, why Runtime.exec() fails in the described Example. Can you reproduce the described behaviour?

Comment: The main drawbacks are - it (`Desktop`) may not be supported on all platforms, but since you're executing `cmd`, you've already narrowed yourself there any way, and you have no control over what application would be used to open the file, as it simply tries to use what ever is configured by the system...

Comment: Do you know how to user Runtime.exec()? It has a lot of pitfalls, so it's not nearly as easy as it looks.

Comment: Actually I am only maintaining legacy code. It was not written by myself. Because of that, I have to be sure, that switching from Runtime.exec() to Desktop.getDesktop.open() does not break the calling procedure for some other files (or file types).

Comment: @Kayaman: Such a comment does not really help. Please explain yourself or provide links.

Answer (score 1):

With `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` you can execute only `executable` file (like `cmd`, `bat`, `exe` etc).
`mpg` isn't executable file, `mpg` file is read by another tool.
You should open it in another way, e.g.

```
Descktop.getDesktop().open(new File("Y:\AAA\DVD2013_GDL_(SEP)\Videos\0005000po8jy.mpg"))
```

Comment: Well, I can call cmd.exe to start the mpg with the default player (as I did). I understand that using Desktop.getDesktop.open() might be the better option, but I still don't know why Runtime.exec() fails for some files and works for others.

Answer (score 1):

[When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). Also, these days you should favour `ProcessBuilder` as it's a bit easier to use.

Comment: the link has changed to https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it worked when you changed the name of the folder from `Videos` to `Video Dateien` seems to indicate that the underlying folder name is not the same as the one that is displayed.

The underlying directory is called `Video Dateien`, not `Videos`. There is a `desktop.ini` file in that directory which is setting the localized name of the directory to `Videos`.

Neither CMD or java understand the localized name of the folder, it is an explorer only concept.

When you use `Desktop.open` it hands off the opening to `explorer`, which understands and translates the localized directory name.

In general, I would never put a localized file name into an application like that, as it is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Hmm... But as I wrote in my question, when pasting the path to the command line, it works with both examples. It fails only when calling cmd from Java

Comment: You never mentioned the version of windows that you're using, which does have an effect on the behaviour; the rules change as the release of windows gets newer - it doesn't work at all with the localized path on windows 8.1 (I don't have an older system to test it on at the moment). The rule of thumb is to use the proper path to the file, rather than a localized/virtualized path.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. I understand that localized paths cause trouble. But why do you think my problem is related to localized paths? All the paths are proper paths.

Answer (score 0):

You need starts player and pass path to file as parameter for it. E.g.

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\default_player_name.exe -param_name D:\\file_name.mpg");
```

Read manual for player what you want starts(how it takes file on input).

P.s. One more good idea: create '.bat'(if you code for windows) script for execute needed programm with parameters, and next time execute this batch-file.

Comment: That's not really an option, because I don't know which player is used by our customers. The desired behaviour is that the default player is launched with the file.

Answer (score 0):

the command in this case would be 'start', so for opening a file

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start \"\" file.mpg");
```

for other uses of Runtime exec apart from launching programs it is worth reading the classic article (also in the answer from Kayman)

[When Runtime.exec() won't](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)

about the pitfalls of java Runtime exec